# How to set SF with pushfq and popfq

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, eflags

As the title suggests I want to set SF=1 (if it was 1 before then I should keep it that way) with the commands pushfq and popfq.

To begin with, I don't understand how would pushing and popping rflags to and from the stack could change flags values.

architecture is Intel x86-64

Comment: Obviously you modify the copy in stack memory at `[rsp]` between push and pop.

Comment: Does that happen since pop and push actually perform some arithmetic operation with `rsp` that will change SF if the operation sign is negative?

Comment: No, *you* have to write an instruction between the push and the pop.  If you just push/pop back to back, you'll restore RFLAGS unchanged.  But you do need the push/pop, otherwise you can only change RFLAGS by running an instruction like `cmp` or `shl`.  Some flags (like CF) have instructions to set/clear/toggle just that one (e.g. `stc`) but there's no such instruction for SF, so if you want to change it without affecting other FLAGS, you have to store/modify/reload FLAGS to somewhere you can use normal instructions on it.